# How to optimize this Code

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-3.0

```
var type = typeof(TInterface);
        var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => type.IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

This code is going slower than I would like. Can someone suggest a more optimal way to code this in C#?

Comment: How did you measure the performance? How often is this code run? What are you trying to do?

Comment: How often does this piece of code get run?  Is there any caching of the results?  Can you tell us what exactly you are trying to determine, and maybe there is another way?  It's hard to suggest alternatives for something you don't know what it's supposed to be doing in the first place.

Comment: @mellamokb.. it Run only once when the application starts in the Asp.net . But the solution by rick was correct i dont want to check for GAC assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over all types in all assemblies you have loaded/referenced.  But the type you want is your type so you know it isn't in any of the system assemblies.  So for example you can filter out assemblies in the global assembly cache if you program isn't installed there:

```
var type = typeof(TInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => !a.GlobalAssemblyCache)
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => type.IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

You can use other filtering strategies to restrict the assemblies to your own if your application is installed in the GAC.

Comment: I was jus testing with the Test framework.. Previously my test took 0.48 sec .now jus 0.17 seconds.. this solution is great

Comment: @satish: If this is going to be called frequently, you can cache the results of `SelectMany` to probably get a bit of a speedup too.

Comment: @Gabe: Unless satish is loading assemblies dynamically, he can just call it once and cache the whole thing.

Comment: @Rick: My initial (apparently incorrect) assumption was that this was a generic function where `TInterface` was a type parameter, thus giving different results on separate invocations.

Comment: @Gabe: No you are not incorrect.  I was too literal.  The right thing to cache depends on what the exact needs are.  Caching `SelectMany` is a great idea if there are many calls.

Comment: @Rick: My assumption was that OP was running this code against many different types. This assumption is incorrect based on the OP's comment (on the original question) that he only runs it once. I had not seen that yet when I made my original comment on your answer.

Comment: @Gabe: So just as you were catching on, I was beginning to doubt myself.  We're quite a pair.  It doesn't matter because your caching point is more important than the specific question.  A query that takes a second has to be taken seriously.

Answer (score 2):

The `ToList()` is entirely redundant, although this is very unlikely to cause any slowdown:

```
var type = typeof(TInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .Where(t => type.IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

FYI the above code should be *relatively* quick, its only at the point where you attempt to enumerate through `types` that the .Net framework does the heavy lifting.

Other than that there is nothing to be optimised without knowing more about what you are trying to do - the above gets an enumeration of all types `t` in all assemblies loaded into the current domain where `typeof(TInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t)` - if there are a lot of types / assemblies loaded then I'm afraid that this is going to take some time.

Can you tell us more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to make plugin system where i need to check all the assemblies for the particulare interface and load it

Comment: @satish Can you not have the plugin provider supply the [assembly qualified type name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) of the type which should be loaded? This would allow you to directly load the required type rather than having to search through all loaded types.